# ElasticSearch and Rails 4.1 - Cannot define multiple 'included' blocks for a Concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Following official documentation from 'elasticsearch-rails' gem, I have the following Concern type of module in app/models/concerns/searchable.rb :

```
module Searchable
 extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include Elasticsearch::Model

    settings analysis: {...}
  end
end
```

But when I run sidekiq (`bundle exec sidekiq`), it crashes with the following error:

```
Cannot define multiple 'included' blocks for a Concern
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport4.1.6/lib/active_support/concern.rb:126:in `included'
c:/Users/Thibault/workspace/EvacuationComplete/app/models/concerns/searchable.rb:4:in `<module:Searchable>'
c:/Users/Thibault/workspace/EvacuationComplete/app/models/concerns/searchable.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

UPDATE

Concern is called in models like this (no include of ElasticSearch::Model):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Searchable
  ...
end
```

Also, in `config/initiliazers/elasticsearch.rb` , I have:

```
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new hosts: hosts,
                                                    retry_on_failure: 2,
                                                    reload_on_failure: true,
                                                    log: Rails.env.development?

Elasticsearch::Model.client.transport.logger = Rails.logger
```

Comment: Do you have `require 'elasticsearch/model'` in your model?

Comment: I don't have this require in my model @Pierre-LouisGottfrois